# How can I layout two equal-width elements with a centered vertical dividing line?

Tags: android, android-layout, layout

I'd like to layout two equal sized views as shown below, arranged horizontally, but with a dividing line in the middle.  How can I accomplish this?

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:weightSum="2"
    android:orientation="horizontal" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:text="A"
        />
    <View
        android:layout_width="1dp"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:background="@android:color/black"
        />
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:text="B"
        />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: I love your [username](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActivityManager.html#isUserAMonkey%28%29) by the way.. :)  Do you cause apps to fail when you touch your device?

Comment: I treat every user like a monkey. It really helps when you test. Haha!